# "solved" laravel eloquent model on table with condition

Tags: laravel, eloquent, model

I want to ask if is possible with eloquent making model with condition on column.
for example, i want to make table users with column role enum('teacher','student')
how to make models for student and teacher?
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use single Table Inheritance (STI) or Sub-classing through this package
[caleb porzio parental](https://github.com/calebporzio/parental)

Comment: Nice.Thank you, thats exactly i looked for ;)

Comment: @PetrKamenSpinar you should accept the answer if it solved your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers